# HTPC Windows 11 lag after turning off TV

Tags: windows, windows-11, lag, htpc

I have this strange problem where my HTPC Windows 11 session becomes very laggy if I turn off my LG TV and then turn if back on. It is super noticeable, the mouse cursor and any video are not smooth at all. I always have to restart my computer to fix it. Curiously this does not happen if Windows enters hibernation and the TV is shutdown automatically because of no signal. I'm not sure if I can blame LG for this. I am using a displayport to HDMI cable supporting 120hz at 4k, not sure if that matters.